# How to write output of child process in Java

Tags: java

I have written a java code in Eclipse and i am developing a plug-in which embed a button on workbench. When this button is clicked, it opens a batch file (located in `c:/program file/prism 4.0/bin`)

The code successfully opens the .bat file ! But my next task is write the output of that batch file on my console. I am using Eclipse IDE version 3.

My code is

```
MessageConsoleStream out = myConsole.newMessageStream();
        out.println("We are on console ! \n Shubham performed action");


try {

      ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\prism-4.0\\bin\\prism.bat");
        pb.directory(new File("C:\\Program Files\\prism-4.0\\bin"));
        Process p=pb.start();

        int exitVal=p.waitFor();            

       out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal+" shown and action performed \n");

            out.println("Shubham Process Successful");
            out.println("Printing on console");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Comment: so where's the question?

Comment: Is this homework? Please ask a real question & give a more explicit title to your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:

```
.....
Process p = pb.start();

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String in;
while((in = input.readLine()) != null) {
    out.println(in);
}

int exitVal = p.waitFor();
.....
```

Note that if the batch file writes to standard error your java program must consume it otherwise the `p.waitFor()` will never return.

Comment: Can you suggest me some answer to this question -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896101/java-how-to-access-file-path-from-preference-page-and-use-it-in-programming-cod/6898143#6898143

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a big favor and check http://commons.apache.org/exec/. It will take care of all the awful details about managnig an external process: timeout, handling input/output, even creating the command line will be easier and less error prone

Answer (score 0):

Note that to correctly read from the InputStreams of a Process, you should do so on separate Threads. See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2458520/127035).

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i used InputStream()

Comment: You can get an `InputStream` from a `Process` using either [Process.getInputStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()) or [Process.getErrorStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream()). In both cases, you should consume the output on separate Threads to the one you do [Process.waitFor()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()) on.

Comment: Can you suggest me some answer with this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896101/java-how-to-access-file-path-from-preference-page-and-use-it-in-programming-cod