# JAVA : How to access file path from preference page and use it in Programming code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My ProcessBuilder class ---

```
 public class HelloWorldAction implements IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate {
IWorkbenchWindow activeWindow = null;

public void run(IAction proxyAction) {

    MessageConsole myConsole = null;
    String name = "outputConsole";

    ConsolePlugin plugin = ConsolePlugin.getDefault();
    IConsoleManager conMan = plugin.getConsoleManager();
    IConsole[] existing = conMan.getConsoles();
    for (int i = 0; i < existing.length; i++)
       if (name.equals(existing[i].getName()))
           myConsole = (MessageConsole) existing[i];

      //no console found, so create a new one
    if (myConsole == null)
        myConsole = new MessageConsole(name, null);

    conMan.addConsoles(new IConsole[]{myConsole});

    IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IWorkbenchPage page = win.getActivePage();

    String id = IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW;
    try
    {
        IConsoleView view = (IConsoleView) page.showView(id);
        view.display(myConsole);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

    MessageConsoleStream out = myConsole.newMessageStream();
    out.println("Prism Button Works !");


    try {           //to clear the console on every click of button

        IViewPart view = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView(IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW);
        if (view != null) {
            (myConsole).clearConsole();
        }
        ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\prism-4.0\\bin\\prism.bat");
        pb.directory(new File("C:\\Program Files\\prism-4.0\\bin"));
        Process p=pb.start();

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String in;
        while((in = input.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(in);
        }


        int exitVal=p.waitFor();            

       if(exitVal==0)
       {
            out.println("Printing on console");

        }
       else
           out.println("Process failed");
    }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    } 
// IActionDelegate method
public void selectionChanged(IAction proxyAction, ISelection selection) {
    // do nothing, action is not dependent on the selection
}

// IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate method
public void init(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
    activeWindow = window;

}

// IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate method
public void dispose() {
    //  nothing to do
}
```

}

My FileFieldEditorClass

```
   public class SAML
extends FieldEditorPreferencePage
implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

public SAML() {
    super(GRID);
    setPreferenceStore(RmpPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
    setDescription("Browse Appropriate files");
}

public FileFieldEditor f;
public FileFieldEditor f1;
public void createFieldEditors() {
        f=new FileFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH, 
            "&Prism.bat File:", getFieldEditorParent());
    addField(f);

    f1=new FileFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH1, 
            "&NuSMV Application File:", getFieldEditorParent());
    addField(f1);
}
public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {
}
```

}

FileFieldEditor class is in com.myplugin.rmp.preferences package
and ProcessBuilder class is in com.myplugin.rmp package,

Now suggest me the way to way to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside your try-block where you construct your ProcessBuilder:

```
 IPreferenceStore store = plugin.getPreferenceStore();

 ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder(store.getString(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH);
 pb.directory(new File(store.getString(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH1));
 Process p=pb.start();
```

Comment: This works with no error, But when i press button to run Prism.bat it shows this error

**java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "" (in directory ""): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified**

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Previously, It was showing the same error. That's why i asked you again. My Preference Page has two **FileFieldEditor** which takes **".bat"** and **".exe"** file respectively. This error means that it is not able to fetch the path from Preference page. Please let me know, How to fix it.
Thank You

Comment: Why are there 2 different plugins (RmpPlugin and ConsolePlugin)? Looks like you're saving the settings for one, but reading from the other. If you really need 2 different plugins, this one might help you (but I never tried this myself): http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html#accesspreferences

Comment: Console plugin is for showing the console screen to print the output.
Actually it is not a plugin, I used it in my plugin programming to print the output. Yeah, But i need to access path from one plugin and use this path in another plugin to run it.

Comment: yeah i need to select path first from preference page and then press *Ok** after this if i click on **Prism button** on workbench, then it should start prism.bat file and show output on console.
But it says file not found....
But

Answer (score 1):

`f1.getStringValue()` returns the field editor's value according to the Javadoc.

In order for your process builder to access the f1 field you must have access to f and f1 in the class creating the process builder. For that you can add these fields in this class constructor

```
public class CreateProcessBuilderClass {

    private final FileFieldEditor f;

    private final FileFieldEditor FileFieldEditor f1;

    // in the method creating the process builder
    ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder(f.getStringValue());
    pb.directory(new File(f1.getStringValue());


}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But the ProcessBuilder code is in another class and another package of the same project. Can you please help me with codes to how to replace ProcessBuilder with f1.getStringValue()

Comment: THe getStringValue() method is public. So you just have to pass the f1 reference to your process builder.

Comment: Do you mean this >

IPreferenceStore store = RmpPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();

        String bat_Path = store.getString(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH);
        ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder(bat_Path);
        pb.directory(new File(bat_Path));
        Process p=pb.start();

Comment: i tried but this is not working, can you please suggest me some way to access f1 in processbuilder

Comment: I have also tried this

RmpPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().getString(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH)

Comment: No. Passing these references at construction time for example.

Comment: -Can you please mention the code? I am not getting your point about passing references at construction time..

Comment: I used your given code and when i am trying to use
private final FileFieldEditor f then it says that selection does not contain a field. I have to access f and f1 in different class in another package.

Comment: RmpPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().getString(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH‌​) should have worked. What was the problem with it?

Comment: @Daniel -  Please refer to the code in question. I tried your method, but it is not working Can you please mention me the code. I am not able to fix this for question for quite a long time. Please let me know

Comment: Please refer to the code in question. I tried your method, but it is not working Can you please mention me the code. I am not able to fix this for question for quite a long time. Please let me know

Comment: @DANIEL - Please refer to the code in question. I tried your method, but it is not working Can you please mention me the code. I am not able to fix this for question for quite a long time. Please let me know

Comment: @Manuel - I even tried of storing the path in string and then tried printing it on console, then too it does not show any output. Which means that it is not fetching path from preference page. Please suggest me what should i do?